# static IP of router

Tags: dns, ip, port

I am trying to ping to a router at my home from a remote location.I am not  guy from networking, so this a thing to inquire about.Till now i was aware that Public IP is never changing IP for a specific internet connection. But after some more research i came to know that Public IP of a router does change depending on your ISP provider.I got this information on [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/163747/why-do-isps-change-your-ip-address/).Can anyone clarify this.Although i got a solution against this at [this link](http://freedns.afraid.org/) but its a bit trouble some when we are dealing with some short of 100 of routers.Also when we talk about a technology where we want to use public IP of user, it will create trouble for us.Can any one suggest me a preferable way by which we can send some information to the public IP of a user without bothering about the fact that it's IP has been changed or not , without relying on any other website that map your Public IP to a name just like DNS provider.

Answer (score 0):

ALL normal Internet IP addresses are dynamic and subject to change at any time.

If you want to run a public server you need to subscribe to a static IP with your provider.

They normally require extra payment for this, and many also want you to subscribe to a more expensive business broadband service.

Which means you can **not** send Data to the Public IP of your user (since it is changing from time to time) as long as he did not engage it, like:

Hey my Name is PC-XXXXX my dynamic IP is XXXX at the moment

Comment: So that means even if we want to convert a simple router to some short of small home based server, that can atleast receive some Http request and revert back , we need to assign our public IP a DNS name.